How can I adjust Maven dependencies?
I have created an API to be used in an application. I would like to reference this API and use it. My guess is that:

I create a jar file for the API.
I put the jar file in some known location (where?)
I reference this jar file in the using POM

In a <dependency> clause. How do I reference the jar file.
Some other way. How?



I have looked at Apache tutorial/POM description/Directory structure and have found all to have errors, not describe terms/tags, to have missing terms/tags, or to have incomplete descriptions. The same is true for the Javageeks Maven book (Apache Maven Cookbook).

Netbeans 22
Windows 10/11-x64
Java (JDK 21)

